# Dishes after dishwasher have salty taste

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

I'm using a dishwasher for some time now and lately we have notice that dishes, especially glasses has a salty taste after they were in the dishwasher.

It is frustrating to drink and have salty taste :( and maybe there are even more chemical residue that we are not aware of.

Anyone encountered this issue and has a resolution?

Washing the dishes with tap water helps but that's also a hassle.

Comment: Check the settings of the diswasher. The salt in there is likely set too high.

Comment: @Willeke tnx but there is no setting for the salt :/

Comment: Check the seal on the water softener, where you put the salt in.

Comment: @Tetsujin i'll try tnx.

Answer (score 2):

1. It could be that the wash water is not being completely drained. Check that hoses are not kinked and that there is an air-break in the waste line to prevent [backflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backflow) of sewage into the machine. Obviously, this could be a health hazard.
2. More likely is that the tap water is slightly salty (e.g. because it is desalinated or from a salt-based water softener), and as it air-dries on dishes, the salt becomes more concentrated. Try hand-drying dishes, or use a rinse aid , such as [Jet Dry](http://www.finishdishwashing.com/products/enhancers/jet-dry/jet-dry-rinse-aid-original/). Also experiment with the best position in the rack so that the rinse water drains well.
3. It could be that you're using too much detergent or that the water is not hot enough to dissolve it..
4. It could also be the brand of detergent in use dissolves poorly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried cleaning the drain, make sure there is air break, as for the water being salty I don't think it so because it wasn't like this in the past. I tried several brands of detergents and also bought Jet Dry, just tried and no help :((

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a dishwasher personally, but salt residue left behind after washing dishes is some issue which can be experienced with or without using a dishwasher.
May be we can start with this check list.

> Check the salinity of your water. [the water used to wash the dishes]
>   Try using a different type of dish washing soap.